# Why do I get "Warning: You are using macOS 10.9" from Homebrew when I have 10.9.5?

Tags: homebrew

I have just reinstalled OS X on my Macbook, I'm trying to get homebrew to install subversion, but I encounter the following error:

"Warning: You are using macOS 10.9.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
YOu will encounter build failures with some formulae."

Comment: You are overthinking the error message. It is referring to macOS 10.9 as a whole being unsupported, not specifically 10.9.0 or 10.9.5.

Comment: 10.9 [.5 or otherwise] went end of life in 2016. Few developers will currently actively support anything older than 10.12, though some may passively support it, until it breaks.

Comment: @tubedogg so basically you're saying that I need to upgrade? I already have all the latest updates installed.

Comment: Perhaps one of you can contribute an answer from your comment? That's spot on

Answer (score 1):

OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) is almost 5 years old, and [has been unsupported since September 2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mavericks).

You'll likely want to upgrade to [macOS Mojave](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201475).